# Laravel: get table of month's dates via Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, php-carbon

I am trying to create a so-called inline calendar for a schedule, where all the current month's dates will be displayed in a 1st table row, like this:

[image]

It should display all the dates of the current months and days of week. Also, in the every `date` cell there will be a select input to choose a work shift, so is it possible to assign some data-attributes to corresponding cell's input (like `data-date`)?

Is it possible of doing that in the Laravel Blade? By the way, I am planning to display the previous month's dates in another table as well (like for reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely possibly. Since it sounds pretty interactive to me, I would probably combine it with a JS framework like `Vue.js`. The benefit of using Vue in this case, is that you won't visibly have to submit a form (meaning that the page will refresh) when selecting a work shift: you can easily do this under the hood by sending an `Ajax` call. It is however not necessary to accomplish what you want.

Using `Carbon`, you can get the days in the current month by doing:

```
$period = Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());
foreach($period as $date)
{
  $dates[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Vue right now. And yes - I was hoping to submit every input via ajax, using simple jQuery. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: That's a possibility as well. Good luck!